# Ajax post не отправляет данные

Tags: javascript, ajax, post

Не пойму что не так, AJAX запрос выполняется, но данные до PHP не доходят.

**JavaScript**:

```
function load() {
  $("#error").text("Загрузка");
}

function load_success(data) {
  $("#error").text(data);
}

$("#form").submit(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/form1.php",
    dataType: "html",
    data: $("#form").serialize(),
    beforeSend: load,
    success: load_success
  });
});
```

**PHP** (form1)

```
var_dump($_POST, $_REQUEST);
```

**Результат**

> array(0) { } array(0) { }

Вот данные:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добавьте `exit;` сразу после `var_dump()`. Сделайте запрос и покажите содержимое вкладки Response

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, вот что пишет во вкладке: [ссылка](https://i.imgur.com/2xrARm6.png)

Comment: Вы показываете респос от двух запросов. Первый - от POST-запроса, но он со статусом 301 - редирект,  а второй от GET-запроса - он не от ajax-запроса. Добавьте exit, сразу после вывода значений массива, как я писал ранее, чтобы не происходил редирект после отправки формы.

Comment: Кстати, не знаю важно это, или нет, но у меня ajax post изначально вообще не работал, писало из-за того, что присутсвует смешаный активный контент. Хотя в htaccess все переадресации на https работают. Тогда я нашёл такой вот способ решения: <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests">. Это может на что-то влиять?

Comment: exit был уже написан, как вы и сказали [ссылка](https://i.imgur.com/u6DzERq.png)

Comment: а почему  ответ 301 на post-запрос? В `form1.php` нет ведь редиректа.  Наверное правила `mod_rewrite` срабатывают в `.htaccess`?

Comment: `RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.
RewriteRule (.*) https://putishestvinik.zzz.com.ua/$1 [L,R=301]`

Comment: покажите закладку Headers для POST-запроса

Comment: Вот: [ссылка](https://i.imgur.com/WBosXgX.png) , [ссылка](https://i.imgur.com/zrEoRYx.png)

Comment: У вас редирект приходит от Nginx на `/form1`. Делайте ajaх-запрос сразу к `/form1` вместо `/form1.php`

Comment: Спасибо огромное!! Ошибка правда смешная оказалась, но очень благодарен. Оставьте ответ чтоли...хоть галочку поставлю)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас редирект приходит от Nginx на /form1. Делайте ajaх-запрос сразу к /form1 вместо /form1.php